# How to programmatically enable Pro trial in Craft 4?

Tags: cli, craft4

In Craft 3, I setup a base build for my team which had a bash script. At one point in the script I was able to enable a Craft Pro trial license like so:

```bash
echo 'Craft::$app->setEdition(Craft::Pro)' | php craft shell/index
```

However, this doesn't work in a version I am doing for Craft 4, and I can't find any changelog or notes about this being removed in Craft 4.

Anyone know if this is intended to happen now? (As in, Craft 4 is supposed to prevent the interactive shell from making changes to a site)

If it is supposed to happen, what could be another solution to get this working?

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of noodling around, I figured out it's as simple as:

```bash
php craft project-config/set system.edition pro
```

Other `project-config` subcommands may be handy as well, such as:

```bash
php craft project-config/diff
```

to show any pending changes made to the on-disk configuration, and

```bash
php craft project-config/apply
```

to apply them.

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to have the `yiisoft/yii2-shell` package installed to run `craft shell`.

From the [Craft docs](https://craftcms.com/docs/4.x/console-commands.html#shell):

> This command requires the yiisoft/yii2-shell package, which you may need to add to your project:
> `composer require --dev yiisoft/yii2-shell`

Then this command should work:

```sh
echo 'Craft::$app->setEdition(Craft::Pro)' | php craft shell
```

[image]

Perhaps test with the interactive shell to see if it works and go from there?

[image]

Comment: Thanks, the shell appears to work already, but the change isn't reflected when I open up the CMS in my browser.

Comment: Try it with the interactive shell? See my updated answer.

Comment: Yep, have done all this and it's still not working.